# Explorer is locking my IE plugin

Tags: c#

I have an IE plugin written in C#. In any moment the user will run an uninstaller or updater to rewrite or delete the plugin's file.

To unregister the plugin on IE I have to run regasm /u for my file, but occurs that the file stills locked (loaded) and I cannot delete it until I reboot the machine.

Actually, the explorer process is locking the file. If I kill the explorer process I will be able to delete the file.

Any idea about how I could delete or rewrite the file without killing explorer's process or rebooting the machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register your IE plugin, put a REG_DWORD set to 1 with Name = 'NoExplorer' in the BHO key (assuming it's a BHO extension), e.g. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects{your guid}

that tells Explorer to only load your extension from within IE, not within Explorer.exe also.

Comment: Thanks @Rory! For future viewers: if your BHO is being locked by `explorer.exe` (because forgot your `NoExplorer` entry), try removing all traces of it from the registry and rebooting. And if at first you don't succeed, try and try again. I had to do this two or three times; `explorer.exe` still had ahold of my DLL *even after rebooting* 3+ times. Hope this saves someone a few minutes of pain!

Answer (score -2):

Rename the old file and write the new file.

Comment: I can't rename the file since it is locked by the explorer process.

Comment: In that case, you may need to use some kind of technique, which makes Windows do it on a reboot. But I cannot remember how to do that.

Comment: We are doing this right now, it is a "run once" registry key. We are trying to avoid reboots, because it is a silent update for our software. Thanks for your help!